# Android Eclipse - Increasing side margins on my table layout

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, formatting, margin

I'm a bit confused on how to increase the overall width of my `TableLayout` in order to become closer to the sides of the screen.

I'm not sure if I adjust this in the actual `TableLayout` itself, or in the parent `RelativeLayout`...??

Image:

[image]

Any thoughts?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="CLR" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="DEL" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="/" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:text="=" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Result"
    android:textSize="55dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match_parent` in the table layout so it takes the full width of the parent then adjust left and right padding to generate the desired separation. Bear in mind that you already have a padding defined in your relative layout hence you you will need to play with both values.

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

Comment: Hey Axis, It's starting to work, but still one problem...the tableLayout perimeter (in blue) is exactly how I want it, but the buttons don't fill the space!! Whatsup?

Comment: Your buttons and rows has wrap_content as their width. As TableRow is a  LinearLayout you should be able to set buttons width to 0 and weight to 1, `android:layout_width='0dp',  android:layout_weight='1'` That way buttons will take all space available proportionately. And finally Tablerow should be use `match_parent`

Comment: Awesome Axxiss, excellent advice. It's almost there...however, I would like my "0" button to appear as one big button, as posted in my original image of the post. How would I do this? I don't think it's possible with the width=0 and weight=1...

You can see the problem here:http://i.imgur.com/SFlssjP.png

Comment: I need to have four buttons on that tableRow because, if not, the three buttons I originally have are all the same size. I only want the "0" button to take up the size of two buttons.

Comment: try setting zero button to weight = 1 and the others two to weight = 0. You will have to play around with those values. Or use a two LinearLayout, one with one button and another with the others two

Comment: Boom!! weight=1 for 0 and weight=.5 for the other two. Works perfectly now. I appreciate all of your help, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to the `TableLayout` which causes it to be just wide enough to show all the content. Try using `match_parent` to make it take the entire parent width:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

Another thing that shrinks your `TableLayout` down is this:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

in the parent `RelativeLayout`. If the first step does not suit your needs, you can try setting lower `paddingLeft` and `paddingRight` values.

Answer (score 0):

try this edit

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.funkycalc.MainActivtiy\" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

the padding values was the problem...